# Python - scipy pdist Between Columns in DataFrame of Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, scipy, dataframe

I am working on a program to calculate the Euclidean distance between movie reviews. I would like it to calculate between a given reviewer and another given reviewer, and a given reviewer and all others. I have the data in a DataFrame of dictionaries like so:

```
{
    'Nancy Pollock': {
        'Lawrence of Arabia': 2.5,
        'Gravity': 3.5,
        'The Godfather': 3.0,
        'Prometheus': 3.5,
        'For a Few Dollars More': 2.5,
        'The Guns of Navarone': 3.0
    },
    'Jack Holmes': {
        'Lawrence of Arabia': 3.0,
        'Gravity': 3.5,
        'The Godfather': 1.5,
        'Prometheus': 5.0,
        'The Guns of Navarone': 3.0,
        'For a Few Dollars More': 3.5
    },
    'Mary Doyle': {
        'Lawrence of Arabia': 2.5,
        'Gravity': 3.0,
        'Prometheus': 3.5,
        'The Guns of Navarone': 4.0
    },
    'Doug Redpath': {
        'Gravity': 3.5,
        'The Godfather': 3.0,
        'The Guns of Navarone': 4.5,
        'Prometheus': 4.0,
        'For a Few Dollars More': 2.5
    },
    'Jill Brown': {
        'Lawrence of Arabia': 3.0,
        'Gravity': 4.0,
        'The Godfather': 2.0,
        'Prometheus': 3.0,
        'The Guns of Navarone': 3.0,
        'For a Few Dollars More': 2.0
    },
    'Trevor Chappell': {
        'Lawrence of Arabia': 3.0,
        'Gravity': 4.0,
        'The Guns of Navarone': 3.0,
        'Prometheus': 5.0,
        'For a Few Dollars More': 3.5
    },
    'Peter': {
        'Gravity': 4.5,
        'For a Few Dollars More': 1.0,
        'Prometheus': 4.0
    }
}
```

I am fairly lost here, but what I would like to know is how to make a function to put each dictionary into a format pdist can work with. Then I can work on how to iterate through it. The code I have so far is below:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
f= open("reviews.txt")
d= eval(f.read())
#print(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
def getSimilarity():
    EcDist = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index) #container for results
    movieArray = df.values
    #some way of turning it into a format pdist can use
    EcDist = pdist#etc
    return EcDist

def getSimilarities():
    EcDist2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
    movieArrays = df.values
    #some way of turning it into a format pdist can use
    EcDist2 = pdist#etc
    return EcDist2
```

Comment: Try tightening this up a bit: e.g., give us three reviews, and a sample of the format you want to end up with from those three reviews.

Comment: k, I will take a look at it when I get home. Thank you.